# Can I ssh and use SAS from the browser in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

At work we have a Linux server with lots of computing power for data science. This server is accessed by several people and it has SAS installed since we need it to run some statistical analyses.

I would like to run SAS from the browser of my local computer, the same way I would do with R Server e.g.

```
 ssh -L 8787:localhost:8787 username@serverid
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? How can it be done? Perhaps connecting SASonDemand to the local server so the tasks are executed in our server and the data never leaves the server? I just want a nice and portable interface to work with SAS. The specs are the following: It's SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M6, and the server is a Debian 4.19.260-1.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I resolved it myself. I installed SAS Studio which is a browser-based interface. Then I can just ssh as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about SAS specifically, but in general if you normally connect to `http://localhost:8787` to use the application when you're local on the machine then yes, I would expect your recipe to work: just connect to the same address on your local machine. You might want to add the `-fN` option put the ssh process in the background, instead of giving you a shell on the remote system.

If you normally access it by some other name, say `http://serverid:8787`, then you *might* find that the web server configuration doesn't recognize `localhost` and won't serve the site even though you connected just fine.

You could also try `ssh -D 8000 username@serverid` and then configure your browser to use a SOCKS5 proxy on localhost:8000.  If you get the settings right you should find that **all** web access happen *as if* you were sitting at that machine.